# REST could not find writer or datasourceprovider for type application/json

Tags: json, rest, writer

I'm creating a REST service which accepts input as PathParam and produces JSON Response. The code is working fine and I can able to build the response. After returning the response, REST is throwing an error like "COULD NOT FIND WRITER OR DATASOURCEPROVIDER FOR (ResponseClass) and MediaType application/json". Thanks.

Comment: "REST is throwing an error" - that's impossible. With the information you give, noone can help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I myself found that the WinkApplication is not loaded properly. The restsdkservice configuration in web.xml was incorrect and because of that **JacksonJaxbJsonProvider** was not loaded into the Wink. Finally got it after 2 days.
 *Thanks everyone!!*

Comment: Any help for people with the same problem?

Comment: Eventually I found some sample code to apply Jackson annotation introspectors to my Wink application.  I updated the code to Jackson 2.x and posted as a separate answer because of space constraints.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got jackson 2.1.3 working with Wink as a JSON provider.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

//see  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jackson/
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

/**
 * @see https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/jax-rs-getting-started.html
 */
public class JaxrsApp extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(YourJaxRSAnnotated.class);
    //...
    return classes;

}
 @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> s = new HashSet<Object>();

    // See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations for more information
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector( TypeFactory.defaultInstance() );
    AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
    AnnotationIntrospector pair = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(primary, secondary);
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(pair);
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(pair);

    // Set up the provider
    JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jaxbProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
    jaxbProvider.setMapper(mapper);

    s.add(jaxbProvider);
    return s;
  }
}
```

then, in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--  this param tells the RestServlet which custom Application sub-class
    will return a list of our classes that have JAX-RS annotations -->
    <init-param>
              <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
              <param-value>com.example.JaxrsApp</param-value>
            </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: It's 2 days that I try to solve this problem. All because everyone use Maven (but where I work don't use it and they don't want to implement it). Thanks to use I was finally able to silve this problem. I know that more updated version of jackson do not have setMapper method but right now I'm just glad I will finally be able to convert json to pojo and back. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Jersey.

First of all, check the dependencies: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1716

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
```